# Scalding NPE only when assigning pipe to val

Tags: scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, scalding

I'm new to Scala and Scalding, and in working on my first Job I'm encountering a NullPointerException when assigning a pipe to a val.  The exact same job that just chains to a `.write()` without the intermediate variable completes as expected.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Are the `StackOverflow_Works` and `StackOverflow_NPE` jobs not equivalent?

**A cut down example that still experiences the issue:**

```
import com.twitter.scalding._

case class Line(timestamp:Float, sessionId:String)


class UserSession () {
  var sessionId = "__default_session_id__"
  var firstTimestamp = 0.0f
  var lastTimestamp = 0.0f

  override def toString() = {
    ("UserSession(" +
      "sessionId:%s, " +
      "firstTimestamp:%f, " +
      "lastTimestamp:%f" +
      ")").format(
      sessionId,
      firstTimestamp,
      lastTimestamp
    )
  }
}


object Predicates {
  def parseLogLine(line:String): Line = {
    val split_line = line.split("\\t")

    new Line(
      timestamp = split_line(0).toFloat,
      sessionId = split_line(1)
    )
  }

  def foldLeftSessions(sesh:UserSession, line:Line): UserSession = {
    sesh.sessionId = line.sessionId

    if (sesh.firstTimestamp == 0.0f) {
      sesh.firstTimestamp = line.timestamp
    }

    sesh.lastTimestamp = line.timestamp

    sesh
  }
}


class StackOverflow_NPE(args:Args) extends Job(args) {
  import Predicates._

  val inputFile = args("input")
  val outputFile = args("output")

  val beaconLog:TypedPipe[String] = TypedPipe.from(TextLine(inputFile))

  val sessions = beaconLog
    .map(parseLogLine)
    .groupBy { b:Line => b.sessionId }
    .sortBy { b:Line => b.timestamp }
    .foldLeft(new UserSession)(foldLeftSessions)
    .values

  sessions.write(TypedTsv(outputFile))
}


class StackOverflow_Works(args:Args) extends Job(args) {
  import Predicates._

  val inputFile = args("input")
  val outputFile = args("output")

  val beaconLog:TypedPipe[String] = TypedPipe.from(TextLine(inputFile))

  beaconLog
    .map(parseLogLine)
    .groupBy { b:Line => b.sessionId }
    .sortBy { b:Line => b.timestamp }
    .foldLeft(new UserSession)(foldLeftSessions)
    .values
    .write(TypedTsv(outputFile))
}
```

**Output of job `StackOverflow_Works`:**
(Runs successfully)

```
objc[49967]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.ReduceStep$$Lambda$89/1583353301.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.ReduceStep$$Lambda$81/252553541.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipe$$Lambda$87/891786282.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipe$$Lambda$87/891786282.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 15:41:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO util.HadoopUtil: resolving application jar from found main method on: com.twitter.scalding.Tool$
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO planner.HadoopPlanner: using application jar: /___/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/scalding-core_2.12/jars/scalding-core_2.12-0.17.0.jar
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO property.AppProps: using app.id: 1B171A71FA8C4402B6BE83737977F803
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO util.Version: Concurrent, Inc - Cascading 2.6.1
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works] starting
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works]  source: Hfs["TextLine[['offset', 'line']->[ALL]]"]["../test-data/stackoverflow.log"]
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works]  sink: Hfs["TextDelimited[[0]]"]["../test-data/stackoverflow-output"]
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works]  parallel execution is enabled: false
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works]  starting jobs: 1
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.Flow: [StackOverflow_Works]  allocating threads: 1
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO flow.FlowStep: [StackOverflow_Works] starting step: (1/1) ...data/stackoverflow-output
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
17/06/01 15:41:26 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO flow.FlowStep: [StackOverflow_Works] submitted hadoop job: job_local918733190_0001
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO flow.FlowStep: [StackOverflow_Works] tracking url: http://localhost:8080/
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local918733190_0001_m_000000_0
17/06/01 15:41:27 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO io.MultiInputSplit: current split input path: file:/___/test-data/stackoverflow.log
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputSplit@401c79fd
17/06/01 15:41:27 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Counter name MAP_INPUT_BYTES is deprecated. Use FileInputFormatCounters as group name and  BYTES_READ as counter name instead
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowMapper: cascading version: 2.6.1
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowMapper: child jvm opts: -Xmx200m
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowMapper: sourcing from: Hfs["TextLine[['offset', 'line']->[ALL]]"]["../test-data/stackoverflow.log"]
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowMapper: sinking to: GroupBy(com.twitter.scalding.TextLine(../test-data/stackoverflow.log)0891c647-0d6d-4c57-92a4-b53608a246e6)[by:[{1}:'key']]
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local918733190_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: file:/___/test-data/stackoverflow.log:0+20350
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local918733190_0001_m_000000_0' done.
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local918733190_0001_m_000000_0
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
17/06/01 15:41:27 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 56102 bytes
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowReducer: cascading version: 2.6.1
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowReducer: child jvm opts: -Xmx200m
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowReducer: sourcing from: GroupBy(com.twitter.scalding.TextLine(../test-data/stackoverflow.log)0891c647-0d6d-4c57-92a4-b53608a246e6)[by:[{1}:'key']]
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO hadoop.FlowReducer: sinking to: Hfs["TextDelimited[[0]]"]["../test-data/stackoverflow-output"]
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local918733190_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local918733190_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local918733190_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/___/test-data/stackoverflow-output
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
17/06/01 15:41:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local918733190_0001_r_000000_0' done.
17/06/01 15:41:32 INFO util.Hadoop18TapUtil: deleting temp path ../test-data/stackoverflow-output/_temporary

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Output of job `StackOverflow_NPE`:**
(Blows up)

```
objc[51212]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.ReduceStep$$Lambda$89/1583353301.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.ReduceStep$$Lambda$81/252553541.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipe$$Lambda$87/891786282.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipe$$Lambda$87/891786282.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN scalding.LineNumber$: Skipping com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipeFactory$$$Lambda$62/1212116343.apply(Unknown Source).getClassName as we can't find the class
17/06/01 16:05:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Throwable: If you know what exactly caused this error, please consider contributing to GitHub via following link.
https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Common-Exceptions-and-possible-reasons#javalangnullpointerexception
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool$.main(Tool.scala:152)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.main(Tool.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$.$anonfun$findReferencedClasses$5(ReferencedClassFinder.scala:48)
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$.$anonfun$findReferencedClasses$5$adapted(ReferencedClassFinder.scala:43)
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$$$Lambda$352/1011104118.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$map$2(TraversableLike.scala:739)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$Lambda$346/1273879638.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:738)
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$.$anonfun$findReferencedClasses$4(ReferencedClassFinder.scala:43)
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$$$Lambda$349/1613514326.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$Lambda$104/95396809.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:191)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:191)
    at com.twitter.scalding.ReferencedClassFinder$.findReferencedClasses(ReferencedClassFinder.scala:40)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job.reflectedClasses(Job.scala:203)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job.config(Job.scala:191)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job.executionContext(Job.scala:223)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job.buildFlow(Job.scala:231)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Job.run(Job.scala:302)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.start$1(Tool.scala:124)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:140)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at com.twitter.scalding.Tool$.main(Tool.scala:148)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Versions of stuff:**

- Scala 2.12.2
- Scalding 0.17.0
- Hadoop 2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.9.2
- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3

  - Build #IC-171.4424.56, built on May 12, 2017
  - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
  - JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  - Mac OS X 10.10.5

Also note that I'm just running these locally in IntelliJ using `com.twitter.scalding.Tool`.

Comment: I think this was fixed here: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/pull/1695 it is a 2.12 related issue.